# Android http callback and fragment handling

Tags: android, android-fragments, callback, httprequest

I have the following code (a skeleton of it):

```
PostRequester(..., Fragment caller, final PostRequesterResponse callback  ) {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, baseUrl,
                response -> {
                    if (callback != null && caller != null) {
                        callback.onResponse(response);
                    }
                })...
```

An example call to the above, from a fragment:

```
...(this, result -> {
            try {
                if (result.contains("error")) {
                    throw new Exception(new JSONObject(result).getString("error"));
                }
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(result).getJSONObject("result");
                tvIncome.setText(getString(R.string.income));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ...showPopup(getString(...));
            }
```

I do check that callback and caller are not null but I get the following:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment x2{8dc73ab (83fe8dc9-f7d2-4324-abf2-c4aae15c37ef)} not attached to a context.
```

It fails the first `getString()` and then fails in the exception's one. Maybe the caller is not null but it is detached. I can add `caller.isDetached()` condition but the user might "go back" and detach the fragment at any time. Checking isDetached after each line of code is not a good idea.

What can be done in this situation? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I see you should call getActivity().getString() just like this :

tvIncome.setText(getActivity().getString(R.string.income))

But also it's a must to check before that getActivity() is not null!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could add `caller.isDetached()` to the callback condition.
As you mentioned, `but the user might "go back" and detach the fragment at any time.` in that case you would not want the fragment to receive the callback anyway.
If you want to handle the response regardless of the fragment, you should not call it from the fragment but from somewhere else, more sustainable.
In that case, I would suggest not involving the fragment in the request logic, only a callback that any caller can register to.

**for your followup question:**

The fragment or whoever needs to get the response, should implement the callback interface. For example: 
1. declare an interface called `INetworkListener` with method `onResponse(Response response)`
2. FragmentX implements INetworkListener
3. In FragmentX override onResponse(Response response) and handle the response there 
4. When you make the network call, instead of the fragment and callback as arguments, use an argument `callback` of type `INetworkListener` (which is whoever implements this interface, in our case, the fragment. so if called from fragment, argument will be `this`.
5. inside your call function, when response is ready call `callback.onResponse(response)` like you're doing now and the fragment will receive it in the onResponse() method that its overriding.

How is it different from what you have now? well, technically its not. 
Basically passing the fragment as an argument may be a source for memory leaks and is not a very good practice.
It is important when you make your call. For example, if you call it in fragment's `onCreate` the response might return before the fragment is attached.
 
The problem with your code is that its not considering the fragment's state before accessing its ui. 
If you want to make an update for the fragment after its resumed, you can use the callback with a check like `if (!fragment.isAdded) return` before updating the fragment's ui in response, in case the fragment was detached.
But if you want to load the fragment *with* the data I would recommend preparing the network data in advance, initialising the fragment with the data and NOT using a callback on fragment for that purpose.

Comment: For simplicity, I have fragment x that needs to show "income". It calls the request and the callback code is part of the function (as you can see in my example). You said not to use the fragment for this, where else can I call it and how the fragment can know the callback should be executed now? Remember that I have several fragments and each fragment retrieves/shows its own data. Thanks.

Comment: For your followup: If I have 2-3-4 http requests in the same fragment, the same "onresponse" will process all of them but that's easy to solve. My main question is: how is it different from what I have now? Why doing this will prevent the "detached" problem?